# LinearLayout : design two views : one at left screen and one at right screen

Tags: android, layout

I have a LinearLayout, in that there is a spinner and a imagebutton. I want that spinner is on left screen and image button is on right screen (and both in same screen). Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/spinner_method_list"></Spinner>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

At above code, I think make `ImageButton` with layout_weight is 1 will work, but in fact, don't. Please tell me how to design this layout please.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` is not a property of `LinearLayout` only `RelativeLayout`. Second, when using `layout_weight` in a `horizontal` `LinearLayout`, the `layout_width` should be 0dp and `layout_height` should be 0dp in a `vertical` `LinearLayout`.

Using a `LinearLayout`, one way to achieve this would be to give each `View` here a `layout_weight` of, say, 1 then create a second `View` in the middle that has a `weight` of maybe 2 but you would need to play with those to get exactly what you want.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/spinner_method_list"/>

    <View
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

A possibly better way would be to use a `RelativeLayout` and use its properties `alignParentLeft` and `alignParentRight`. Something like

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"   <!-- here  -->
        android:id="@+id/spinner_method_list"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>    <!-- and here  -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want them each to take up half of the screen then you could just give each a `layout_weight` of "1" and a `layout_width` of "0dp".